# How can I add a UIBezierPath to a UIView that uses auto layout?

Tags: swift, autolayout, uibezierpath

In my project I want to add a line to a `UIView` (this `UIView` uses auto layout).
I'm using `UIBezierPath` and `CAShapeLayer` to draw the line.

This is my code:

```
let myView = UIView()
self.view.addSubView(myView)
myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
myView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
myView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true

let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: myView.frame.height/2))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: myView.frame.width, y: myView.frame.height/2))

let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 11.0

myView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

But my problem is no line shows in viewController.
When I use this code everything is OK and the line shows perfectly:

```
let myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 160, width: 100, height: 40))
self.view.addSubView(myView)
```

How can I solve this problem? I must use auto layout.

Comment: Hi Behrad, can you, please, name the view you created differently, e.g. myView or something else. Then first add the path to the view before you add it as a subview to the view of the view controller?
The way I read your code, is that you are adding the path to the view of the view controller.

Comment: Hi MacUserT, I change my code.

Comment: Let me know if It worked.

Comment: and I do as you say but not working.

Comment: Hi Behrad, I tried to run your code. The frame of your view is (0, 0, 0, 0) and the frame you added too.

Comment: you are right, but after running the app, you can see the myView is showing in top right corner.this is happening because after finishing the compiler and running viewDidLoad, start to draw the UIView and setting frame for theme.

Comment: I think it is because `myView.frame` has zero size when you are adding the layer. Try using `myView.bounds` instead.

Comment: still have a same problem.

Comment: @behrad If the size of your view isn't going to change the fix is really easy. Will the size of your view change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a custom `UIView` subclass and set your layer's path in `layoutSubviews()`. That way you get the proper frame when needed.

Here's a simple example:

```
class LineView: UIView {

    let shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 11.0

    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.midY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.midY))

        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath

    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myView = LineView()
        myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(myView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            myView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
            myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            myView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor),
        ])

        // if you want to see the frame of myView
        //myView.backgroundColor = .yellow

    }

}
```

Result - with yellow background so we can see the frame, and with your constraints (you probably want to use safeArea...):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I found your problem. You have defined a UIView with a frame of (0, 0, 0, 0). If you then draw a line in that view with the coordinates of that line related to that view, you get no line.

I assume that you want your view to be on 0, 160 with the height of 40 and width of 100. The line should then run from (0, 20) to (100, 20).

In that respect are your constraints not rightly set, since your view ends up in the top right outside the screen.

I made the following code that might help. You set your constraints how you like it.

Make a custom view (MyLineView) like this:

```
import UIKit

class MyLineView: UIView {

    private let lineColor = UIColor.black

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        lineColor.setStroke()
        path.lineWidth = 11

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.origin.x, y: self.frame.size.height / 2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: self.frame.size.height / 2))
        path.stroke()

        print(self.frame)
    }
}
```

Then you can code your view controller like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

//        let myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 160, width: 100, height: 40))
        let myView = MyLineView()

        let viewPositionX: CGFloat = 0
        let viewPositionY: CGFloat = 160
        let viewWidth: CGFloat = 100
        let viewHeight: CGFloat = 40

        let topConstraint = viewPositionY + viewHeight - self.view.frame.size.height
        let widthConstraint = viewWidth - self.view.frame.size.width

        myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

        self.view.addSubview(myView)
        myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: viewPositionX).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: viewPositionY).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: topConstraint).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: widthConstraint).isActive = true
    }
}
```

I just added the green background color to see where the view is. This works on my phone. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using rightAnchor, topAnchor, widthAnchor and heightAnchor so the view showing in the top right corner and it is inside the screen not outside. and I use your code but still not working.

Comment: I think, I have no way to use UIBezierPath when using auto layout. I must use UIView (with 1 height value) instead of UIBezierPath for draw line. :(

Comment: I will come with another solution later. Give me dome time. Currently in calls. Your view has no dimensions.

Comment: DonMag find a solution and it is good solution. I want to thanks you too, for your help.